Would light travelling through curved, expanding space, experience a Doppler shift due to the expansion of the space?
Assume the curvature is spherical.
Below is a link to a related question, but that became bogged down on the issue as to whether a sound signal travelling around the surface of an expanding balloon, a curved, expanding 2-dimensional space, would experience a Doppler shift. After numerous comments there was one answer - the sound signal would experience a Doppler shift due to the expansion of the balloon. But that answer was incorrect, as shown in the replies. So we can start from the belief that in the 2-D case, the sound signal will not experience any Doppler shift due to the expansion of the balloon. So the question boils down to 'can the 2-D result be extended to the 3-D case as in the question.
The relativistic Doppler effect is a function of relative velocity. But does the velocity also have to be non-zero relative to the travelling signal?
3-D space can only be curved in the presence of a 4th dimension. That dimension must be perpendicular to the original three dimensions. The expansion of a 3-dimensional space can only be in the direction of this 4th dimension. One can imagine a 3-dimensional space could expand uniformly along each of its three dimensions but that would imply a centre in the 3-dimensional space, which is not allowed, at least as far as our universe is concerned. The expansion must be in the direction of the 4th dimension which is perpendicular to the direction anything can move in the 3-dimensional space. This is very closely analogous to the expanding balloon in 2-dimensional space.
Is there any reason why the result in 2-dimensional space cannot simply be extended to the 3-dimensional case, light will not show any Doppler shift due to the expansion of space, if that space is curved? I know once relativity gets involved, things may not be so simple.

what is the actual question? 2D gravity doesn't work, light is totally different from sound. Is there a point, and can you explain it clearly?

This Veritasium video might help - What Actually Expands In An Expanding Universe?

@JEB 2D gravity doesn't work, true, but the Doppler effect does not require gravity. The question is to ask whether the 2D case can be simply extrapolated to 3D.

You may be interested in this post on Astronomy.SE


3-D space can only be curved in the presence of a 4th dimension. That dimension must be perpendicular to the original three dimensions. The expansion of a 3-dimensional space can only be in the direction of this 4th dimension. One can imagine a 3-dimensional space could expand uniformly along each of its three dimensions but that would imply a centre in the 3-dimensional space, which is not allowed, at least as far as our universe is concerned. The expansion must be in the direction of the 4th dimension which is perpendicular to the direction anything can move in the 3-dimensional space. This is very closely analogous to the expanding balloon in 2-dimensional space.

Basically, nothing in this paragraph is correct. Even a 2D space can be intrinsically curved. Nothing about intrinsic curvature in a lower dimensional space implies the existence of extrinsic curvature in a higher dimensional flat space. There are a variety of embedding theorems describing the higher dimensional flat space that would be required to isometrically embed a lower dimensional curved space. But the existence of such a flat embedding space is not necessary for describing intrinsic curvature in the lower dimensional space. It is an additional structure, and not one for which there is any physical evidence.

light will not show any Doppler shift due to the expansion of space, if that space is curved?

Light will unambiguously have a redshift in a FLRW expanding spacetime. Whether you call that a "Doppler" shift or a "gravitational" shift is basically a matter of terminology.
For typical emitters and receivers at low velocities in the comoving coordinates you would describe it as gravitational.
But comoving coordinates are not the only valid coordinates. Instead, you could use Fermi normal coordinates along the path of the light from the emitter to the receiver. In those coordinates you would describe the redshift as entirely due to Doppler shift.
The nomenclature makes little difference, but the redshift itself is unambiguous. The change of coordinates does not make any change in any physical observable. It only changes what things are called.

But I suppose there is a 4th dimension nevertheless.
I knew about gravitational redshift. It seems really difficult to make Doppler redshift alone equal cosmological redshift (but maybe not impossible). Can it be done?

Is it possible to have curved space in one frame of reference and flat space in another?

@JohnHobson you are certainly free to suppose the existence of an additional dimension, but what is wrong is a statement like "3-D space can only be curved in the presence of a 4th dimension". That is simply false. I will update my answer to clarify and to include Fermi coordinates in which the redshift is Doppler  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates

I've heard of intrinsic curvature, but there is a 4th dimension so wouldn't the curvature of space be extrinsic?

@JohnHobson No, because that's not how spacetime curvature works. The spacetime curvature according to GR affects both the three spatial dimensions and the one temporal dimension. So you will need more than four dimensions for the curvature to be  extrinsic.

@JohnHobson I have already told you in your previous question that gravitational redshift is a form of Doppler shift, which you rejected. Observers are not stationary in spacetime; they move toward the future. So the observers in a gravitational well are moving in spacetime; just not spatially.

@Amit. But what about this. If you solve the FLRW metric for a universe consisting solely of curvature, the result is a Hubble sphere expanding at the speed of light (it can't be a ball, it must be a 3-sphere I think). The time dimension appears to be linear. So while the curvature of spacetime may be intrinsic I would say the curvature of this 3-sphere is extrinsic, it is expanding along the direction of time.

@Vincent Thacker. Re the previous comment. In that model, cosmological redshift is 100% due to gravitational time dilation so in that model cosmological Doppler redshift is zero. Which is what is behind the question.
     Doppler redshift is temporary. When the velocity stops the redshift stops. Gravitational redshift is permanent, it is a function of position only, when the velocity stops the redshift remains. This makes it harder to accept they are the same thing viewed from different frames of reference - but I suppose velocity can stop in one frame of reference, but not in another.


@JohnHobson I can't understand your statement technically without actually seeing the equations you're referring to. But let me say in general you're making a misuse of terminology. No matter how certain terms in the equations "appear" when written in specific coordinates, we don't learn anything fundamental about the type of curvature. The latter is a coordinate independent property of the spacetime (manifold). There also seems to be a contradiction in what you wrote: a 3-sphere has four dimensions. If its curvature is extrinsic, again you need more than four dimension to account for that.

@JohnHobson it is very difficult to answer questions in comments since it is such a small space. If you want a back and forth discussion then you should try physicsforums.com. I am Dale there also

@Amit. Mathematically a 3-sphere is 3-dimensional. Any point in a 3-sphere has an address consisting of three numbers. (You could use 4-dimensional polar co-ordinates but the radius would be a constant and so can be removed.)

@JohnHobson I stand corrected. But with regards to this business of not ascribing too much importance to how things look in a specific choice of coordinates, let me also refer you to an answer for an earlier question of yours by John Rennie. I think the same message is also very valid for this discussion.

@Amit. John Rennie's answer is directly contradicted by Vincent Thacker, above. And John Rennie's answer regarding the 2-dimensional case is simply wrong.

@JohnHobson It's not a contradiction, that's the whole point of what John Rennie wrote. You can ascribe the redshift to the expansion in specific coordinates that are also the ones we commonly refer to when discussing this subject. Idk what you're referring to about the 2d case.

@Amit. John Rennie's was the only answer. I am referring to that.

@JohnHobson I don't see how there is a contradiction. My point is that in relativity there is no absolute motion (indeed, that's the whole point) so whether a velocity is spatial or temporal depends on the observer. There is no privileged separation of the two, not even in flat spacetime.
